# How to stop and disable CUPS service in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, printing, snap, services

I have noticed with `top` that the `cups-browsed` process is taking all of my RAM and CPU. This is apparently an [open issue](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups-filters/issues/130) as of today. I want to disable it to make my computer usable again.

Previous answers suggest using `systemd stop`. But cups is not listed when running `systemd`, and calling `systemd stop` on it returns something along the lines of: non existing service.

According to top, the command used to launch it is:

```
cups-browsed -c /var/snap/cups/common/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an *open issue* ?   If it's a bug, please provide the BUG ID so we can explore what you're referring to.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how ram is utilised in Linux. If all your ram is being used, it's a good thing, no? You've not paid for something you're not using.

Comment: @24601, yes but still a single background process which normally uses less than 1% of my memory suddenly using 8GB, is concerning. I understand the OS hogs unused memory, but a normal process doesn't randomly allocate 8 GB

Comment: No unfortunately, you still haven't got it. Unused RAM is wasted RAM. In simple terms, even though various utils will report that you are using all your RAM, when you launch a new program, the kernel will absolutely provide memory to that application. Same applies with CPU usage.

Comment: @24601 Yes but: (1) it's not the same thing all the RAM being used in the machine (which is great), than all the RAM being used by a specific single userland process that shouldn't be using it. (2) AFAIK ~100% CPU usage (as reported by top) is not normal for a Unix computer on idle (normal for me is ~1% and it went back to that as soon as I killed cups).

Comment: comments is not the place to discuss this. I still think you're misunderstanding how Linux works under the hood but if you still have a question about RAM usage then ask a separate question

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
sudo snap stop cups
sudo snap disable cups
```

Explanation:

It seems you are running the snap version of the service. That cannot be managed by systemd. You can see the services running under snap by using:

```
snap services
```

After running the aforementioned commands it should yeld:

```
Service            Startup   Current   Notes
cups.cups-browsed  disabled  inactive  -
cups.cupsd         disabled  inactive  -
lxd.activate       enabled   inactive  -
lxd.daemon         enabled   inactive  socket-activated
```

Showing that you have stoped (`inactive`) and prevented from autostarting on boot (`disabled`) `cups.cups-browsed` and `cups.cupsd`